# I getting this error: "Fatal error: Uncaught Error:" with Composer

Tags: php, class, composer-php, fatal-error

I am trying to add a Class with Composer. But I am getting this error.

```
use Insanlik\Request;
use Insanlik\Erisim;

Request::Giris($configure);
Erisim::updateAlanAdi($auth, $data = array());
```

Print:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Request' not found in /home/insanlik/public_html/system/ajaxs/Cekirdek.php on line 1784
Error: Class 'Request' not found in /home/insanlik/public_html/system/ajaxs/Cekirdek.php on line 1784
```

Line 1784:

```
Request::Giris($configure);
```

Where am I making mistakes?

---

P.S: This Class works well on a clean PHP page but I get this error when I add main PHP page.

Comment: I assume you've installed the library with `composer require`? Start by checking that the class exists in the `vendor` directory

Comment: I've checked.@Daniel

Comment: Try to run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: I did, the result did not change. @Daniel

Comment: Can you add the rest of your error message to your post?

Comment: I updated my question. @Daniel

Comment: *This Class works well on a clean PHP page but I get this error when I add main PHP page.* - your probably not including the autoloader.

Comment: All the Classes are working with Composer but only this Class is not working @LawrenceCherone

Comment: Have you tried adding `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` at the top?

Comment: Yes, I have already `autolad.php` -- just now I tried this method; `$require = new Insanlik\Request();` and `$require->Request::Giris($configure);` i got this error: `Notice: Undefined property: Insanlik\Request::$Request in [..]` and `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in` @Daniel

Comment: `$require->Request::Giris($configure);` - that does not look like valid PHP code after all....

Comment: Do you have a method on your mind? @NicoHaase